# Can't seem to figure out why my javascript isn't working in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Question I have this js and for some reason it isn't working in IE or Chrome but, it does work in FF and help would be greatly appreciated.

Side note I need this to be a change function-- for some strange reason click function works in IE and Chrome but, in this situation I need it to be a change, also this a RubyRails application.

Here is my code ..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#emp_id').change(function () {
       var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id=" + $(this).val();
       $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            if (!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
                $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
            if (!(data.emp_last_name === undefined))
                $('#emp_last_name').val(data.emp_last_name);
            if ((data.error * 1) == 404) {
               alert("The employee ID entered was not found!");
               } else {
               window.confirm("Your employee ID was found please fill in the email(optional) and password fields then click the sign in button to register.");
               }
           });
       });
   });
```

I also tried this still didn't work in IE & Chrome

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#emp_id').on('change', function () {
       var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id=" + $(this).val();
       $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            if (!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
                $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
            if (!(data.emp_last_name === undefined))
                $('#emp_last_name').val(data.emp_last_name);
            if ((data.error * 1) == 404) {
               alert("The employee ID entered was not found!");
               } else {
               window.confirm("Your employee ID was found please fill in the email(optional) and password fields then click the sign in button to register.");
               }
           });
       });
   });
```

Tried this as well still did not work in IE and Chrome

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#emp_id').keyup('onchange', function () {
       var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id=" + $(this).val();
       $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            if (!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
                $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
            if (!(data.emp_last_name === undefined))
                $('#emp_last_name').val(data.emp_last_name);
            if ((data.error * 1) == 404) {
               alert("The employee ID entered was not found!");
               } else {
               window.confirm("Your employee ID was found please fill in the email(optional) and password fields then click the sign in button to register.");
               }
           });
       });
   });
```

Here is my view code

```
    <div class='row form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
       <%= f.text_field :emp_id, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_id', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
       <%= f.text_field :emp_first_name, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_first_name', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
       <%= f.text_field :emp_last_name, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_last_name', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? Is the change event being triggered? Is the Ajax call being made? Is there an error processing the Ajax call (aka https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) You are going to need to debug this.

Comment: the alert is a custom alert and i just used confirm cause i was being lazy and did want to create to separate alert boxes lol. @ epascarello

Comment: It seems like the change function isn't working because when I change it to click it works and the ajax works as well so I'm pretty certain it has something to do with the change function. @epascarello

Comment: So what is the element the event is attached to? What is "emp_id"

Comment: emp_id is a text_field ill update my question with my view code @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Change event only triggers, when the input field loses focus.

EDIT:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('#emp_id').change(function () {
   var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id=" + $(this).val();

   $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);

        if (data.emp_first_name !== undefined) {
            $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
        }

        if (data.emp_last_name !== undefined) {
            $('#emp_last_name').val(data.emp_last_name);
        }

        if (parseInt(data.error) === 404) {
           alert("The employee ID entered was not found!");
        } else {
           window.confirm("Your employee ID was found please fill in the email(optional) and password fields then click the sign in button to register.");
        }
   });
});
```

EDIT #2: I think, there was a syntax error in my example code...

Comment: That is correct because once a user  clicks on another box or hits tab it works  but, its only working with change in FF @marcel

Comment: "What is not working exactly? Is the change event being triggered? Is the Ajax call being made?" - epascarello

Comment: You can use the debug mode from the browser to find out, what the problem is... or add some well placed console.logs...

Comment: is the type of `data` string or object?

Comment: then try adding `data = JSON.parse(data)` at the beginning of the change-function

Comment: That worked but now my alerts aren't showing up @marcel I get a console error syntax errror JSON parse unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: What is the exact value of data (before `.parse()`)?

Comment: the value would be for emp_first_name would be BILL and for emp_last_name it would be SMITH @marcel

Comment: the syntax erro rJSON parse unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data is coming from this line data = JSON.parse(data); @marcel

Comment: i think this means, that the data string has a wrong format... give me the result of `console.log(data)` (BEFORE the `.parse()`-call).

Comment: here is the log before the .parse call----- > Object { user: null, status: "unprocessable_entity", error :404 } @marcel

Comment: also from the log  Object { emp_first_name:  "BOB", emp_last_name: "SMITH"   }

Comment: i think, that is the problem.... this is not correct json syntax. a json object have to look like this: { "prop1":"value 1", "prop2":"value2" }... or in your example { "emp_first_name": "BOB", "emp_last_name":"SMITH" }. the missing quotation marks on the properties make the parse-function throw an error.

Comment: how would i fix this? @marcel

Comment: You have to change the method on the server, that creates the response with the json object.... unfortunately I don't know RubyOnRails, so i can't help you writing this function...  sry

Comment: But i am pretty sure, that there already exists a function to create a json string from an object...

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#emp_id').keyup(function() {
    var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id=" + $(this).val();
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      if (typeof(data.emp_first_name) !== 'undefined')
        $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);

      if (typedof(data.emp_last_name) !== 'undefined')
        $('#emp_last_name').val(data.emp_last_name);

      if (parseInt(data.error) == 404) {
        alert("The employee ID entered was not found!");
      }
      else {
        window.confirm("Your employee ID was found please fill in the email(optional) and password fields then click the sign in button to register.");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: this worked on IE Chrome and FF but, it only allowed me to type one letter then then it fired the ajax. is there a way to change that ??

Comment: @Snowman1234: I thought that was what you were going for. You pretty much either have to do it this way (per char), use `change` (focus has to leave input), or you can do something fancier with timers that will allow you to wait for user pauses before firing the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out... all I had to do was change this $('#emp_id').change(function () { to this $('#emp_id').blur(function () { a